# Why is this Django view being executed twice on post?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have a Django view that signs a user up to a free trial through Stripe. When the view makes a POST request, it does so twice.

I've tried idempotency keys, both after the `if request.method == 'POST'` line and in the initial rendering of the view. The customer in Stripe always ends up with two identical payment sources and two identical subscriptions to the plan.

```py
def start_trial(request):
    title = 'get started'
    description = title
    form = MembershipForm()
    key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    trial_days = 30
    coupon = None
    custom_message = ''
    subscription_idempotency = str(uuid.uuid4())
    source_idempotency = str(uuid.uuid4())
    try:
        vendor = Vendor.objects.get(user=request.user)
        custom_message = vendor.message
        coupon = Coupon.objects.get(vendor.coupon)
        coupon = coupon.stripe_coupon_id
        trial_days = vendor.trial_days
    except Vendor.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    try:
        partner = Partner.objects.get(user=request.user)
        custom_message = partner.message
        coupon = Coupon.objects.get(partner.coupon)
        coupon = coupon.stripe_coupon_id
        trial_days = partner.trial_days
    except Partner.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MembershipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            plan = Membership.objects.get(type_of=form.cleaned_data['plan'])
            # stripe needs to attempt to create a customer
            # TODO what if there's already a membership/subscription?
            user_membership = UserMembership.objects.get(user=request.user)
            stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                items=[
                    {"plan": plan.stripe_plan_id}
                ],
                trial_period_days=trial_days,
                coupon=coupon,
                idempotency_key=subscription_idempotency,
            )
            subscription = Subscription.objects.create(
                user_membership=user_membership, stripe_subscription_id=stripe_subscription.id)
            subscription.save()
            stripe.Customer.create_source(user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                                            source=request.POST.get('stripeToken'),
                                            idempotency_key=source_idempotency)
            user_membership.membership = plan
            user_membership.save()
            user.is_subscriber = True
            user.save()

            # if subscription status is incomplete, display error.

            # if passes, redirect to onboarding
            message = 'yay'
            messages.success(request, message=message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/onboarding/')
    return render(request, 'memberships/free_trial.html',
                  {'title': title, 'description': description, 'form': form,
                   'key': key, 'custom_message': custom_message})
```

Data always ends up in Stripe twice. Log shows:

```
[18/Jun/2019 11:05:21] "POST /memberships/free-trial/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Jun/2019 11:05:22] "POST /memberships/free-trial/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Comment: This and the timestamps separated by a second on these requests makes me think you have some duplication in your front-end/view javascript "The customer in Stripe always ends up with two identical payment sources and two identical subscriptions to the plan." --- what code are you using there? are you using Elements or Stripe.js v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108826/duck) for pointing me in the right direction. I had unseen (to me) JavaScript duplicating what was happening in the view. Removed the offending file and the problem is solved.